# How to find a pointer in a game?

Tags: heap-memory, reverse-engineering, readprocessmemory, cheat-engine

I am trying to find the offset/pointer for FIFA 22 timed finishing.

For example, if you double press "D" it will activate the timed finishing mechanic.

If you press them too quickly, too late or in the right time it will show like this "TOO EARLY" "TOO LATE" "EARLY" "GREAT TIMING"

I am trying to find this offset to modify, so everytime you shoot with timed finishing, so it will appear" GREAT TIMING" even if you don't do it right.

In FIFA 20, the offset is right here, in the attached photo.
Memory adress : 142BEC9A and you need to modify the C5 into C7, and all shots will be with green saying great timing.

But in FIFA 22, I cant' find it.

Can someone help me please, how do I know where to look? I mention I didn't found fifa 20 memory adress alone, I just got it from someone's cheat engine table.

How do I know where to find that memory adress for fifa 22 ?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tk_F...channel=247CTF

Here it's a video so you can know how this game mechanic works, here in fifa 21, I had timed finishing hack activated, and as you can see, all shots were perfect.

How do I find that offset/pointer? Because it's not like searching for HP or Ammo in a shooter, to search 100, get some damage, and then do some rescan.

In the photo I posted, the adres 142BECD9A it's responsible 4for timed finishing.

The only thing I should do in that dump, is to modify the C5 into C7, and voila, all shots will be perfect.

My question is, how do you find this to modify in FIFA 22??

[image]

Comment: In order to find a pointer you first have to find the actual address of the value you're looking for. Then, you can use the techniques that the Cheat Engine Tutorial teaches you in order to find a reliable pointer to that address. Since the previous version of the game has that same mechanic, it probably shares similar functionality, meaning that in the new game, that variable should have the same values corresponding to the same times. You'll probably have to see how it works in the old game is what I'm saying, so that you know what to search for. As for how it was originally found, IDK.

Comment: It could be that that address has a bit mask of some kind. I don't really know how it works. But changing the C5 byte to C7 seems like it's an enum or bitmask or something like that. I'm thinking that the way it might have been found was by viewing some area of memory where a pointer to some other value was found, something easier to find like a game clock or something. The memory that has to do with timed finishing might be nearby, since it could be in the same object. There's a ton of tricks for finding things, it's an art. The way I've had success is by sinking weeks into just exploring.

Comment: But yeah, I would first look at how that existing cheat table works, and try to understand everything it's doing. If you don't understand how that table works then you probably don't know enough to find that value on your own, I'm just guessing.

Comment: @RandomDavis https://postimg.cc/5YBBHDmT 
Look, this is the code inside the cheatengine table for timed finishing>

I understand what this code does, it search for the adress of TIMED Finishing and change the C5 to C7

Comment: I don't know how Cheat Engine scripts work so unfortunately I can't really offer any further insight.

Comment: When there where few changes in fifa 22 binary compared to fifa 22 you can use binary diffing tools like https://github.com/joxeankoret/diaphora. But when the code was heavily changed or mechanics of the timed finishing was changed, this technique will not help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I don't personally own or play FIFA, but i've looked at the mechanic and can give you a few tips as to how to find it. But before that keep in mind that finding a code and knowing how to modify it is not a trivial task, like finding a value and changing it and may require you to have way more experience with cheat engine, game logic and assembly.

What you are trying to find is an instruction or instructions somewhere in the code which are responsible for figuring out how well you did the timing shot. There are many ways to get there, but my usual method is to start by finding a value very closely related to the instruction.

For example: If you are looking for an instruction that executes when the player gets damaged, you should probably find the player health, since it will likely be modified by that instruction.

With FIFA i noticed there is a bar that appears over the player's head when he does the timing shot in which bar there are lines moving towards the center. There is likely a value associated with the current value/position of that bar. Maybe when it's in the red zone the value is:10, and when it's in the green zone it might be 95-100.

To find it you can use the speedhack to slowdown your game and then search for unknown float/4 byte value and search for incremented.

Once you find the value play around with it and see if you can force it to be such that it always gives you the 'Great shot'

For changing the code:
With the value in hand you can use a 'find out what writes to that address' to find the code that modifies that value. If you can understand it and the instructions around it, you may be able to write a script that always sets it to a value that would cause it to give you 'Great timing'